# Setting hover style in react-native-gifted-chat

Tags: react-native-gifted-chat

How do I set the styles for hovered links in [`react-native-gifted-chat`](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat)?

For example, I've currently got

```
const renderBubble = (props) => {  
    return (
        <Bubble
            { ...props }
            linkStyle={ {
                left: {  color: 'gray', textDecorationLine: 'none' }
            } }
            textStyle={ {
                left: { color: 'white' },
                right: { color: 'white' },
            } }
            wrapperStyle={ {
                left: { backgroundColor: '#8fafff', borderRadius: 5 },
                right: { backgroundColor: '#2dc4b3', borderRadius: 5 },
            } }
        />
    )
}
```

but don't see in the source code or docs for the package where I can control the hover color for links.